# Scroll to bottom of datagridview in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Using VB.NET and trying to scroll to the bottom of the datagridview.  Everything I've read says to set
FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex to Rows.Count - 1, but that just shows the row above the last one and doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom.  I thought maybe it was a C# to VB thing and that the index needed to be just Rows.Count, but that threw an error, as expected if 0-indexed.

I also tried selecting the last row, but same result.

```
    If dgv.RowCount > 0 Then
       dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.Rows.Count - 1
       dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Count -1).Selected = True
    End If
```

Comment: Not having ever tried this, but if it's going to the 2nd to last record, would would happen if you simply dropped the "-1" out of the above statements?

Comment: I just edited the post for that, I tried it and it threw an error.

Comment: Whereabouts in your code are you placing those lines? When I try it with a sample DGV and put those lines in the Constructor it won't work. However, move them to the _Load_ event (or behind a _Click_ event) then it works as expected

Comment: I tried moving it to the load and that did seem to help.  It's showing the top of the desired row and not the whole thing, but better than before.  Thanks.

Comment: @JacquelynK, can you post a screenshot of what the grid looks like?

Comment: If by chance you are setting the DataSource of the DataGridView to say a DataTable then consider using a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=net-5.0), Set change the data source of the DataGridView to the BindingSource and set the DataSource of the BindingSource to the DataTable. Now when you want to move to the last row in the DataGridView use the MoveLast method of the BindingSource.

Comment: Are you expecting the row at index `(dgv.Rows.Count - 1)` to be located at the top (beneath the column headers) of the DGV?  That will only happen if the DGV is sized such that only one row is visible. When multiple rows are displayed (normal case), setting `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.Rows.Count - 1` will scroll the control to the bottom of its `DisplayRectangle` such that the last row is displayed, but it will not be the first displayed row with empty space below it.

Comment: I appreciate your responses.  I think the issue is that we have some cell formatting going on that isn't done yet when it tries to scroll.   I was able to get it to go all the way to the bottom when I put the scroll option in the CellFormatting event, but then I obviously couldn't scroll back up since it kept scrolling me back down on the repaint.  At least I think I know the problem now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add a timer that ticked a few times resetting the FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex to the last row each time and allowing the grid to redraw.

The problem was the CellFormatting event dynamically changing the height of the rows based on content.  I believe this event fires every time the grid needs to be redrawn - such as when scrolling.   I'm assuming it sets the scroll point based on the base height of the rows multiplied by the row number, but the formatting pushed the rows down.  Not the most elegant approach, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To select the last row:

```
dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows(dgv.Rows.Count-1).Cells(dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting: dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.Rows.Count - 1

in the RowPostPaint event worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).